# Genexus 9 Database Reverse Engineering Tool (DBRET 1.3) doesn't show table names

Tags: mysql, genexus, genexus-dbret

I'm using **Genexus 9** with Java web Upgrade 4. I'm trying to use the **Database Reverse Engineering Tool (DBRET 1.3)** reading a mySQL database with **mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar** driver but I can't see table names!

It shows me a list of tables but they appear without names. Can you help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This is a known error in DBret with mySql 5.x or up and JDBC, that was fixed in dbret 1.4.1 (Genexus Ev3 build 86.435) .

As a WA you can try using **ADO.NET** with **MySQLDriverCS**, in this case works ok.

Also you can use dbret of Genexus Ev3 or the 1.4.x standalone version.
Here you can find more detail in the sac 254870 : 
http://www2.gxtechnical.com/portal/hgxpp001.aspx?15,4,61,O,E,0,,25480
, you need to be logged in.